# Textfield shouldchangecharactersinrange swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am making an iPad-app to learn english words. It needs to check the input in a textfield as soon as the characters are typed in the textfield.
I am using the swift function shouldChangeCharactersInRange to accomplish this.

My code:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range:NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        if TextField1.text == "apple" {
            checkImageView1.hidden = false
        }
        else {
            checkImageView1.hidden = true
        }

        return true
    }
```

It needs to show an image if the word is typed right, in this case "apple".
The problem is that when te user types in the "e" of "apple" the check only sees "appl" and therefor doesn't show the image.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use a target on your `textField` with the control event `EditingChanged` instead of the delegate method.

**Swift >= 1.0**

```
myTextField.addTarget(self, action: "didChangeText:", forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)
```

**Swift 3.0** (String literal selectors are deprecated, use #selector)

```
myTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didChangeText(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

Then use the targeted method to run your checks.

```
func didChangeText(textField:UITextField) {
    if textField.text == "apple" {
        checkImageView1.hidden = false
    } else {
        checkImageView1.hidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Why this is not a connectable action in IB I will never know.

Comment: There is a bit of change in syntax in Swift 3.0 as follows. myTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didChangeText(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)

Comment: @Wez no problem. Thank for your answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

While Wezly's answer is correct, the reason why it's only seeing "appl" instead of "apple" is because the text of the `textField` isn't updated with the latest entry at that point, as the name of the delegate method states `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`. Instead of checking the text of the `textField`, you should do the replacement of the new entry and check the new value with something like below:

**Swift 3**

```
let newText = textField.text?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
```

Using the event `EditingChanged` would work if you just want to get the latest value, but if you want to do some validation of each entry **before** the text is actually edited, you have to go with the delegate method.

Comment: `textField.text` return `String` and `replacingCharacters in: with:` needs an `NSString`. So you should do something like this instead: `let newText = (textField.text as! NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the delegate method, attach a method to the event "Editing Value Changed" and accept the textField as the sender.

In the viewDidLoad method:

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldEdited:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
```

This is the method which will get activated

```
func textFieldEdited(sender: UITextField)
{
    var text = sender.text
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code. This function gets the new string value being added in variable `string`. If you concatenate it with textField1.text, you will get full string in textField.

```
    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range:NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        var startString = "" + TextField1.text+string     //Now this should be 'Apple'
        return true
    }
```

Comment: That won't work if you use backspace or some other text manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3**
As *chengsam* correctly mentioned: `replacingCharacters in: with:` needs a `NSString`. So you need to do something like this:

```
let newText = NSString(string: textField.text!).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
```