# how to save textField.text while editing

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I'd like to save textField.text while editing. If I tap save button and call savePressed function while editing(before textFieldShouldEditing function is called), textField cannot get self.name data. Could you tell me how to save data, if savePressed function is called before textFieldShouldEndEditing func is called?

```
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {  //delegate method

    self.name = textField.text

    return true
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {   //delegate method

    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}

func savePressed(sender: UIButton){
    var parameters = [
        "id":   currentUserId,
        "name": name
    ]
    Alamofire.request(.POST, uri.usersApi + "/save_profile", parameters: parameters as? [String : AnyObject], encoding: .JSON)
        .responseJSON { (request, response, data, error) in
            var jsonObj = JSON(data!)
    }

    fetchData()
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the following code, I've solved the problem.I referred this.[Textfield shouldchangecharactersinrange swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603449/textfield-shouldchangecharactersinrange-swift)

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: "didChangeText:", forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)
func didChangeText(textField:UITextField) { 
}
```